# OUT parameters don't work for some users

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, stored-procedures, out-parameters

I have an Excel worksheet that needs to make a number of calls out to a MySQL server. Here's the VBA code, simplified to illustrate this issue:

```vb
Public Function Connect() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "<Server>"
        .Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "<DB>"
        .Properties("User ID").Value = "<User>"
        .Properties("Password").Value = "<Password>"
        .CommandTimeout = 1500
    End With
    Set Connect = cn
End Function

Public Sub TestSProc()
    Dim cxn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim p1 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim p2 As ADODB.Parameter
    Set cxn = Connect()
    cxn.Open
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cxn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "OutParamTest"
    Set p1 = cmd.CreateParameter(, adBoolean, adParamOutput)
    Set p2 = cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamOutput, 255)
    cmd.Parameters.Append p1
    cmd.Parameters.Append p2
    cmd.Execute
    MsgBox "Result: " & p1.Value & " / " & p2.Value
End Sub
```

This executes the following stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `OutParamTest`(
    OUT `isAvailable` BIT,
    OUT `remarks` VARCHAR(255)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  SET isAvailable = false;
  SET remarks = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
END
```

On my machine, and for *almost all* users, this returns:

> Result: False / The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

But for *one* user, it returns:

> Result: True /

The only difference I can find between my machine, and the user's is the MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI and Unicode Driver versions. I have version **5.03.02.00**, and originally this user had an older version. I asked him to upgrade, and he now has version **5.03.09.00** (newer than mine), but the problem still exists.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there some kind of machine-level configuration variable that could cause `OUT` parameters to stop working? Or do `OUT` parameters only work in some select driver versions?

---

**UPDATE:** I modified the SP as follows:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `OutParamTest`(
    OUT `num` INT,
    OUT `remarks` VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  SET num = 12345;
  SET remarks = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
END
```

And made the corresponding changes in VBA. Now on my machine it returns:

> Result: 12345 / The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

And on this user's machine it returns:

> Result: 232718680 /

Comment: I fail to see how this MCVE could ever return `True` for `p1`, but it's an interesting question regardless.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Agreed, that is odd. My working hypothesis on that is that somewhere along the line, it ends up trying to do a type conversion.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MySQL, but I presume `Set isAvailable = false` is setting it to `0` (assuming `false` is defined as such somewhere). Does explicitly making it `0` change the outcome? Making the stored procedure return a constant / explicit `0` would rule out the possibility of the SQL being the problem (...although, assuming all users connect to the same server, that should already be ruled out)

Comment: Check [Bug #83698](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83698).

Comment: @Mat'sMug That doesn't change the results. However, when I changed the parameter to an `INT`, I got much more interesting results. See my updated question. To my eye, it looks like it could be returning a *pointer* rather than the actual value.

Comment: ok now *that* is even more interesting. and... I've no clue lol

Comment: @wchiquito We are using MySQL 5.7.17 so this could indeed be affecting us. The proof I guess would be downgrading the connector to 5.03.04 as  Remco Kuijer suggests, and see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*@wchiquito*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084213/out-parameters-dont-work-for-some-users#comment83145089_48084213) pointed out that this is likely related to MySQL [Bug #83698](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83698), and even though I've been unable to replicate the precise behavior elsewhere (due to my company's peculiar network set up and security restrictions) I agree that this is most likely the culprit.

Since asking this question, I've re-written the stored procedure and associated spreadsheet to return data *only* via a Recordset. It's not nearly as 'clean', IMO, but at least it works on all users' machines. Still, if anyone can find a way to get `OUT` params to work (or if MySQL ever decides to fix this bug) please let me know.